# Time complexity for modified binary search which calculates the mid as high - 2

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity, binary-search, asymptotic-complexity

I have to find out the time complexity for binary search which calculates the dividing point as mid = high - 2 (instead of mid = (low + high)/2)
so as to know how much slower or faster the modified algorithm would be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst-case scenario is that the searched item is the very first one. In this case, since you always subtract 2 from n, you will have roughly n/2 steps, which is a linear complexity. The best case is that the searched item is exactly at n-2, which will take a constant complexity. The average complexity, assuming that n -> infinity will be linear as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can derive the answer based on the recurrence formula for binary search.

We have  T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + O(1)

Since we divide in two equal halfs, we have floor(n/2). You should rewrite the given formula to describe the modified version. Furthermore, you should use Akra-Bazzi method to solve the recursion formula for the modified version since you are dividing in two unbalanced halfs.